# exec proxy not found for :: YoutubeVideoPlayer :: openVideo

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4 app

- I am trying to play Youtube video in my app using youtube video
  player (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/youtube-video-player/)

after I run command `ionic cordova run browser`

I am getting issue

> exec proxy not found for :: YoutubeVideoPlayer :: openVideo

I am sharing my code in ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player/ngx';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor(private youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer , private navCtrl: NavController) {}


  watch(watch) {
    this.youtube.openVideo(watch);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply can't run youtube video on a browser by using a plugin, the supporter platforms are Android and IOS please build the apk or ipa are try to run in actual device.